# changing hue and saturation in pixel level

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors, pixel, hue

I'm working on a image processing project where i need to change the color of the object. For that i have performed a threshold operation and obtained object pixels as shown in the image.  After that i have applied the various colors to object using setPixel method in c#. But this method destroy all the characteristics of the images. But actually i need something like the bottom images. I obtained the them by editing in Adobe Photoshop by changing hue and saturation. can you guys make any suggestions how do this.
code example appreciated, thanks in advance.

#### Original Image

[image]

### Threshold Image

[image]

### Color Applied Image

[image]

### Required Image

[image]
[image]

Comment: its worth take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964257/faster-method-of-changing-an-image-hue

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your concrete problem? We won't do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the hue, saturation, and brightness of every pixel from the RGB values ([RGB<->HSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv/1626175#1626175)). Then play with them, and convert the image back to RGB.